# Want to apply for asylum but I have 2 year ban

Tags: united-kingdom, asylum

I left my home country St Lucia and came in Britain in 2007 at the age of 8 with my dad and my sister. To my knowledge now, they overstayed but then applied for the right to remain.

We went to a lawyer and they offered to support our case. We sent in all the stuff they asked for and paid all the fees needed, then ten years later after I turned 18 in February 8 2016, they denied us the right to remain then during the process of returning we found out that the lawyer never sent in any of our documents to support me and my dad that I was my dad's daughter, so the lawyer lied and stole our money.

Now after returning to my home country I am now being threatened by people which we owed money to and they are after me to kill me and I don't feel safe at all in my home county, the police wouldn't do anything to protect me.

I want to apply as a refugee in Britain  as it's the only country I know and have family there do you think I would be granted it or not? As I have a 2 year ban also.

Comment: In the sort of life-or-death situation you describe, step 1 is to get to a safe country and apply for asylum there. Any safe country. Now. Worry about trying to get to where you have lived and have family later.

Comment: Normally asylum claims are meant for protection against your government or when the situation in your country has become so unstable that your government can longer protect you. Could you call the authorities, explain the situation to them, and get protection from them? I am not aware that St Lucia is having any major socio-political problems at the moment.

Comment: @outflak is correct. That is the case in most countries, including the UK. You wouldn't be eligible for asylum, even without the situation of the ban.

Comment: Does someone want to add a full answer here? I think the comments are correct.